# Get Asp.Net username from SQL Server 2008?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

With windows and sql server accounts, I can access the logged in user with functions like: user_name() or suser_sname().

Can I access the user that is logged into asp.net in the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it lives in another world. SQL Server only sees it's own connection, technically it does not even know (or care) there is ASP.NET on the other end.